# Almost uniform convergence and $L^1$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a **finite** measure space. Then it is well known that in this case uniform convergence implies $L^1$-convergence.

Now let's weaken the notion of uniform convergence and let's introduce the almost uniform convergence (a.u.-convergence) as defined here:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Almost_Uniform_Convergence

and now my question:

Is it true that a.u.-convergence  implies $L^1$-convergence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $X = [0, 1]$ with the Lebesgue measure and consider the sequence $(f_n)_{n \geq 2}$ where
$$ \forall x \in [0, 1], \qquad f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
n^2 x & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1/n \\
2n-n^2x & \text{if } 1/n \leq x \leq 2/n \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
This sequence converges almost uniformly to $0$, however we have $\|f_n\|_1 = 1$ for all $n$, which prevents the $L^1$ convergence.